# AutoFill EditText Android

Tags: android, android-edittext

I'm trying to create a search bar like.
I have to use a particular autofill, infact I can't use a dropdowns menu.

For example if I write *Noce* the edittext will have to suggest *Nocera* in the same editText, like this.

[image: kind of hint I think]

but if the user write something else the pointer have to the end of the typed text (in this case Noce) and the hint have to disappear.

Is there some library that allows me this?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have solved this using two EditText in the same position. The first one is a normal editable EditText, the second one is not editable from the user but is used to show the hints programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

There's this library that will fulfill some of your requirement called [Auto Fill EditText](https://github.com/nntuyen/auto-fill-edit-text)